# Cyclone V SE use FPGA to add additional HPS RAM

Tags: fpga, soc

As near as I can tell, the Cyclone V SE HPS HMC accesses up to 512Mo per chip select, limiting the CPU to 1Go of physical RAM.

I can't find documentation indicating if the HPS can be instructed (i.e. configure the MMU) to address another memory controller on the FPGA to access expanded RAM.  The documentation for Xilinx devices (UltraScale+ MPSoC) indicates 32Go maximum capacity plus additional via the FPGA fabric, indicating those devices can do such a thing.  I've seen no such thing for Intel's FPGA SoC.

If not, the only solution (for the Cyclone V SE) would be a DIMM controller on FPGA and an OS that treats *that* RAM as system memory, using the 1Go HPC RAM as a giant cache area.  Modern OSes already do this:  add a driver exposing your big RAM area as a block device and provision the entire device as swap (for S&G, use zswap to manage the swap area as compressed RAM and expand its effective capacity).

Just a curiosity.

Comment: What's your question? (Can you add your question to your posting?)

Comment: I am familiar with the 'b' (bit) unit and the 'B' (Byte) unit for memories but I have no idea what an 'o' unit is....